# Parsing Out Data from ps faux output (not sure how to awk it!)

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, scripting, grep

So I have been working on reverse engineering a script based on output from ps faux.  I've gotten it to work mostly, however I'm running into an issue with how it tallys up the PHP processes.  For example, this is the output of the script that I'm trying to replicate:

`Top SQL
Apache statistics: CPU %: 0 | Mem %: 1.8
Total PHP statistics: CPU %: 0 | Mem %: 83.9
Top PHP Users
391 user -> CPU %: 0 | Mem %: 83.9
Top PHP Scripts
307 /home/user/public_html/gg/ajax_calls2.php -> CPU %: 0 | Mem %: 70.7
36 /home/user/public_html/gg/support/crm/index.php -> CPU %: 0 | Mem %: 5
8 /home/user/public_html/gg/support/advanced_search.php -> CPU %: 0 | Mem %: 1.5`

What I am having the most trouble with is grabbing the running php scripts, for each user, and then counting each process and tallying the CPU / MEM usage for each one.  The AWK statement that I have written so far only outputs a single script for each user, rather than all of the scripts for each user.

This is what I have so far:

Variable declarations:

`function join2 { local IFS="$1"; shift; echo "$*"; };ix="0"; ixx="5"; count="0"; count2=$(ps faux | egrep -w 'usr/bin/php|/opt/php*/bin/'|awk '{print $1, $3, $4,$14, $15}' | wc -l);`

First I store all of the PHP processes from ps faux in an array:

`initialARRAY=($(ps faux | egrep -w 'usr/bin/php|/opt/php*/bin/'|awk '{print $1, $3, $4,$14, $15}'));`

Then I wrote a loop to join the elements of the array into one line (since the array separated each field on a different line) so that each array element is the entire PHP script line from ps faux:

`while [[ $count -lt $count2 ]]; do memARRAY+=("$(join2 ' ' ${initialARRAY[@]:$ix:$ixx})"); count=$(( $count + 1 )); ix=$(( $ix + 5 )); done`

The contents of the array memARRAY is below:

```
root@server [~]# printf "%s\n" "${memARRAY[@]}"
user 0.0 1.0 /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/cart.php
user 0.0 0.9 /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/cart.php
user3 0.0 0.2 /usr/bin/php /home/user3/public_html/manager.php
user3 0.0 0.4 /usr/bin/php /home/user3/public_html/manager.php
user3 0.0 0.3 /usr/bin/php /home/user3/public_html/manager.php
user3 0.0 0.2 /usr/bin/php /home/user3/public_html/search.php
user3 0.0 0.1 /usr/bin/php /home/user3/public_html/search.php`
```

Without the spacing since I don't know how to copy and paste into stack without weird spacing issues.

Now the issue that I am running into is that when I try to count the processes per user, while also tallying and summing the CPU / MEM usage of each script, the final output only shows one script, rather than the 2 scripts that are running for user3.

This is the part that I believe is not working properly:

```
    for i in $(printf '%s\n' "${memARRAY[@]}" | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq ); do echo -e "Resource Usage by Script:\n $(printf '%s\n' "${memARRAY[@]}" | grep ${i} | awk '{ x+=$2; y+=$3; z=$4; w=$5; count++$5 }END{print "     Procs:",count,"",z,w,"","CPU: ",x,"%"," ","MEM:", y,"%"}')\n";done"`
```

The output of the above line is something like this:

```
    [[ User Information for: user3 ]]
    Resource Usage by Script:
          Procs: 2  [ /usr/bin/php /home/user3/public_html/search.php ]  CPU:  0 %    MEM:  0.4 %
    [[ User Information for: user ]]
    Resource Usage by Script:
          Procs: 10  [ /usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/cart.php ]  CPU:  0 %    MEM:  9.9 %`
```

As you can see it only calculated and tallied one out of the two scripts running for the user3 user.  I'm at a loss for how to have it calculate and output all of the scripts for each user.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: IMHO, way too much info here. Boil this down to 2-4 lines of input data, (include a record that should pass thru without change, and if needed, a record that should be flagged as an error). Show your required output from those inputs, and trim your code down to just what is needed to create that output. Else, use `print "Debug: $0=" $0` type statements in awk, and `set -vx ; bash_cmds_to_test ; set +vx` to debug the  bash parts. Good luck.

Comment: There is no actual errors, and the script runs completely fine.  If I had to put it simply, I just need to be able to grab all of the PHP scripts from a ps faux output, and then sort them based on user, number of times hit, and also tally the total memory / cpu usage for each script.  I was experimenting with awk but hit a dead end.

Comment: You're aware that you can specify the format of `ps` output, right?

Comment: Yes I am aware but I am trying to understand how the person referenced at the start was able to pull that information from ps faux, and have it output like that.  I've tried everything that I know of other than tracking that person down (impossible).  I need it so that it formats it as something along the lines of:

[# of instances of script] [script name] [cpu usage] [mem usage]

For each script for each user in ps faux.